# Search result warning: You don't appear to have permission to view the account credentials for this result source.

Tags: result-source

I am using SharePoint 2013. I login on the production environment with the farm account. I go to central admin and go to the search service application. I go to the results source. I click on the default result source "Local SharePoint Results". I cannot edit this result source because everything is readonly. I see also a warning:

> You don't appear to have permission to view the account credentials
>   for this result source. You need permissions at the level at which the
>   result source was created. For example, only an account with
>   administrator permissions for a Search Service application can view
>   the account credentials for a result source created at that level.

How can I edit this default result source? Or how can I see which account has permissions to edit this result source?

Comment: Login with the account that runs the search service application, should be your standard service account, of if you are using dedicated search account.

Comment: I just tried to access the result source in my VM and i think it's locked down by default. You could make a copy of the result source and make modifications to it.

Answer (score 1):

Local SharePoint Results is a system default result source. You can not modify it. You can copy and create a new one and modify that instead...